# Error: Could not find or load main class org.grails.cli.GrailsCli

Tags: grails

I'm trying to start a Grails 4 application in Intellij, the project is configured with Java 8 and Gradle seems to be loaded correctly, but it gives me the following error:

```
error: Could not find or load main class org.grails.cli.GrailsCli
```

Is there any know method in which I can get around this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, check if the language level and SDK are correct (File > Project Structure > (Project/Modules) > Language Level)

From [360learntocode' blog post](https://www.360learntocode.com/2022/07/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class.html):

> This might be due to the removal of some dependencies or libraries
> from the application. Sometimes, while loading multiple applications
> from IDE while downloading the library for a particular project other
> libraries for another project might remove so this kind of error might
> occurs for that project.
>
> Let's first delete the ***build*** folder under the application.
>
> Now, let's refresh the Gradle project. Here we are using IntelliJ
> Idea, we can refresh the project as below
>
> [image: Refresh dependencies Gradle]
>
> Image description:
>
> 1. Click Gradle on the right tab;
> 2. Select the project;
> 3. Click refresh.
>
> After refreshing the project it will download the missing
> dependencies. Then run the application which will resolve the problem.
>
> ---
>
> We can also try cleaning the application.
>
> If we are using the command line then type the following command to
> clean the application.
>
> ```
> grails clean
> ```
>
> If we are using the IntelliJ idea then <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> opens the command
> window and use the following command.
>
> ```
> clean
> ```
>
> Now, re-run the app.

Comment: FYI... some of that is only relevant if you are using Ultimate Edition.